# Can I make old Vim treat Alt key mappings <M-..> as Esc-prefixed, like Neovim and other CLI software(e.g. bash) do?

Tags: key-bindings

Do Vim users use Alt key for mappings? If yes, how exactly?
As it is known, there are 2 common ways of handling `Alt` key in CLI software: either `<Esc>`-prefix or 8-bit. It seems like Vim chooses the later way while a lot of other CLI software(e.g. `Neovim`, `bash`, `tmux`) chooses the former one.
From `intro.txt`:

```
 4.  "<key>" means the special key typed.  This is the notation explained in
     the table above.  A few examples:
           <Esc>                Escape key
           ...
           <M-a>                Meta- a  ('a' with bit 8 set)
           <M-A>                Meta- A  ('A' with bit 8 set)
```

Given my terminal emulator is configured to emit `<Esc>`-prefix(and it is proven by `showkey -a`), does it mean that instead of `nnoremap <M-y> :echo hello<cr>` I should map `nnoremap <Esc>y: echo hello<cr>`? Or there is some option which I missed or trick that I don't know about?

Comment: From my experience, you should be able to map `<esc>x` in your case. In your terminal, with `<c-v><a-x>`, you will be able to check the sequence that is received. That's what you want in your map in vim. The `^[` character represents a `<esc>`, I recommend using the latter.

Comment: OFC I am able to map with `<esc>`, but since I am gonna use these mappings with `Alt` mapping with `<M-..>` seems more straightforward. So I would like to know if it is possible and how Vim folks usually deal with `Alt`-mappings

Comment: Thanks for te clarification. I think you'll be able to do that with both `eightbitinput` and `metasendsescape` unset in your terminal. Enabling the former should allow mappings like `<A-x>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I cannot. While in practice it usually works well enough, Vim creator thinks it is [a bad idea](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/4974#issuecomment-536302763).
So, either `<Esc>` prefix should be mapped explicitly

```
nnoremap <Esc>y :echo 'hello'<cr>
```

or special `:set-termcap` option should be set in before:

```
execute "set <M-y>=\ey"
nnoremap <M-y> :echo 'hello'<cr>
```